# Converting Date to String in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am working on SQL server 2005. While inserting specified date in the database by this format:
(`10/11/2012 00:00:0:00`)(`MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:s:ms`).

```
select CAST(day(column name) AS CHAR(2)) + ' '
   + CONVERT(CHAR(4), column name, 100) + ', '
   + CONVERT(CHAR(4), column name, 120) as Coupon_expire
from Admin
```

I can't convert this date to this type (`Wednesday, October 11, 2012`), please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATENAME(weekday,'10/11/2012')
      + ', '
      + DATENAME(month,'10/11/2012')
      + ' '
      + convert(varchar,month('10/11/2012'))
      + ', '
      + convert(varchar,year('10/11/2012'))
```

Try this.

Comment: +1 for a good solution, one minor detail. In my opinion, instead of using default length, you should always specify the length of the varchar.